# Visual studio running in parallels file issue

Tags: macos, mac, visual-studio-2010

I'm using parallels desktop 10 with windows 8.1 on a macbook air with OS X Yosemite. I have installed the latest Visual Studio on it and I'm coding in c/c++. The problem I have that when I try to open a file, doesn't matter if I write the full path or not, the file cannot be open for some reason. I have heard about other people using mac and parallels to do the same as I and have the same problem, the only fix was using boot camp. However I wanted to know if there is a solution for this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

So I found an answer to my problem somehow by changing the registry files of my windows according to this link:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/156276